# NullPointer Exception when getting array size on some devices

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I get nullpointer exception when getting the size of an array. I only get nullpointer exception on some device.

I have a class called ExerciseStartActivity. Here I call the randomize method.

```
public class ExerciseStartActivity extends Activity{    
     private Exercise currentExercise;  
     private FitnessExercise myExercises;
     private int exerciseNbr;
     private int maxExercises;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //..
    ....
    ....
    //

    initExercise();
}

   private void initExercise() {
    exerciseNbr = 0;
    Exercise[] exercises = loadExercises(SavingData.getDifficulty());
    myExercises = new FitnessExercise(exercises);
    myExercises.randomize();
    maxExercises = myExercises.nbrOfExercises();
    nextExercise();
}

private Exercise[] loadExercises(int difficulty) {
    Exercise[] exercise = null;
    switch(difficulty){
    case R.id.radio_easy:
        exercise = difficultyEasy();
        break;
    case R.id.radio_medium:
        exercise = difficultyMedium();
        break;
    case R.id.radio_hard:
        exercise = difficultyHard();
        break;
    }
    return exercise;
}

private Exercise[] difficultyHard() {
    Exercise[] exercises = {new Exercise("Push-ups", "pushup", 40),
            new Exercise("Leg-up Crunches", "crunch_leg_up", 90),
            new Exercise("Crunches", "crunch", 90),
            new Exercise("Bicycle Crunches", "crunch_cycle", 100),
            new Exercise("Jumping Jacks", "jumpingjack", 100),
            new Exercise("Squats", "squats", 30),
            new Exercise("High Knees", "highknees", 120),
            new Exercise("Lunges", "lunge", 30),
            new Exercise("Bench Dips", "bench_dips", 40),
            new Exercise("Knee Push-ups", "kneepushups", 80)
            };
    return exercises;
}

 }
```

I have a FitnessExercise class with the randomize class:
In this class I get null pointer exception when randomize() method is called.

```
public class FitnessExercise {  private Exercise[] exercises; // Array
 with all the questions
     private int index = -1; // Index of the question
     private Random random = new Random();
     public FitnessExercise(Exercise[] exercises){
        this.exercises = exercises;
     }

     public void randomize()
    {
         int swapPos;
         Exercise message;
         for (int i = exercises.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
         {
             swapPos = random.nextInt(i + 1);
             message = exercises[i];
             exercises[i] = exercises[swapPos];
             exercises[swapPos] = message;
         }
     }

 }
```

Here is the errors:

> 

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.playsimple.fitnessapp/com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> com.playsimple.fitnessapp.FitnessExercise.randomize(FitnessExercise.java:34)
> at
> com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.initExercise(ExerciseStartActivity.java:74)
> at
> com.playsimple.fitnessapp.ExerciseStartActivity.onCreate(ExerciseStartActivity.java:67)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
> ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `loadExercises` may return null?

Comment: I have now added the loadExercises(). But why is it returning null only in some cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading your exercises are `null`.

```
Exercise[] exercises = loadExercises(SavingData.getDifficulty());
if (exercises == null) {
    // no exercises were loaded
    // maybe create default exercises here?

} else {
    myExercises = new FitnessExercise(exercises);
    myExercises.randomize();
    maxExercises = myExercises.nbrOfExercises();
    nextExercise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty easy to understand. Just read the stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
    com.playsimple.fitnessapp.FitnessExercise.randomize(FitnessExercise.java:34) at 
    ....
```

You are trying to access an instance which is actually `null`. I do not know what is the line 34 but a possible candidate is :

```
// You do not check if "exercices" is not null
for (int i = exercises.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

Maybe this line returns `null` in `initExercise()` :

```
loadExercises(SavingData.getDifficulty());
```

Comment: I have now added the loadExercises() check above. But why is loadExercises() method returning null only in some cases only?

Comment: probably that sometimes you're passing a correct "difficulty". So your switch does nothing and the return value remains null.

Comment: I have checked my code and can't find why it returns null. It works perfect in most of the devices. It crashes on some device because I have the crash report.

Comment: you do not handle the case where difficulty is not `R.id.radio_easy` or `R.id.radio_medium` or `R.id.radio_hard`

Comment: I have handled that case to. Like this: default: exercise = difficultyEasy(); break;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lies in these 3 lines :

```
Exercise[] exercises = loadExercises(SavingData.getDifficulty()); // may return null
myExercises = new FitnessExercise(exercises); // the null is passed to this instance
myExercises.randomize(); // the null is referenced here
```

You haven't included the code of `loadExercises`, but based on the exception you got, it's likely that this method returns null in some cases. This null is used to initialize the `FitnessExercise` instance, and causes the `NullPointerException` in `randomize()`.

I suggest that instead of returning null, you return an empty array in `loadExercises`.

Comment: I have now added the loadExercises() check above. But why is loadExercises() method returning null only in some cases only?

Comment: @user3730218 What happens if the passed `difficulty` doesn't match any of the cases in your switch statement? I suggest you change the first line to `Exercise[] exercise = new Exercise[0];`.

Comment: Can I ad this in the switch case instead;  default:
   exercise = difficultyEasy();
   break;
  }

Comment: @user3730218 Yes, that would work, assuming `difficultyEasy()` doesn't return null.

Comment: I still get the error although I added the default statement in the switch case.